# Web service to upload a file throwing exception

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

I am using RestEasy and I want to write a web service for file upload. So, I have written the following code -

```
@POST    
    @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
    public void post(   @PathParam("param1") String param1, 
                        @PathParam("param2") String param2,
                        @PathParam("param3") String param3,
                        @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse, 
                        @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                        MultipartInput input){
        for (InputPart part : input.getParts())
        {
            System.out.println(part.getMediaType());
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

But when I try to hit the web service using the REST client in chrome, I get the following error in server logs -

```
failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:375) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:113) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
```

While sending request from REST client, I choose method as "POST", content type as "multipart/mixed" and attach a file (have tried without attaching a file too but same error comes). Error on client is 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

Comment: Try `multipart/form-data` for the Contenty-Type!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multipart/form-data to upload a file using REST webservice

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "C://" // your storage location path
            + fileDetail.getFileName();

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```